# Locking the camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera

Please help, i need a suggestion.

I am going to keep a button in my app. Which must lock the camera. The camera(hardware) must not to be used by any of the other camera applications. It should only unlock wen i press unlock button in my app.

and also a small doubt wat does "camera.lock();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DeviceAdmin and set camera as disabled on pressing button you could enable it .Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setCameraDisabled%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Ya. Thats good. But i have doubt in it. They have specified as "Since : API level 14" in their properties. Whether it could be used for all levels? Or else it wil work only above the levels specified??

Comment: it will only work above api 14. But what i have seen is most commercially available phones have implemented this functionality before api leevel 14. You could use reflection and check. But that could be a problem if you are going to use app on multiple phones